# How to restore normal child positioning behavior after calling `setX()`

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` that is contained in the following `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/percentage_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:minWidth="35sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:digits="0123456789."
        android:gravity="right"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/percent_sign"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="%"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I want to do is when the number is empty, position the percent sign at a particular x position within its parent, like so:

```
private void resetNumber() {

        float newX = ((LinearLayout) percentSignTextView.getParent()).getWidth() 
                   - percentSignTextView.getWidth() 
                   - pixelsFromDimen(R.dimen.percent_sign_right_margin));
        percentSignTextView.setX(newX);
}
```

And this works perfectly. The problem is restoring the automatic positioning behavior of the `LinearLayout` after setting the x position of `percentSignTextView`.

Before setting it, as the number changes, the width of the number `EditText` changes, and the percent sign moves with it. Resulting in the percent sign always at the end of the number. But after setting the x position, `percentSignTextView` will not move at all, regardless how much the number is changed.

I've tried resetting the `LayoutParams` of `percentSignTextView` and I've tried removing it and adding it back as a subview of the `LinearLayout`, but neither worked. How can I restore the default behavior after manually changing the x position?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout, making percentage TextView relative to the right of the EditText

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="100"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="%"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

To have always text centered try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/myEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="%" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: yes, I would suggest putting them in a Relative Layout, put the % to be `android:layout_toRightOf=""` and it will move automatically, to be at the end

Comment: @rosualin This doesn't work either. Same problem as with the `LinearLayout`. Works as expected, until `setX()` is called, then afterwards the automated positioning behavior won't return when the number `EditText` becomes unempty.

Comment: @shoe what does not work? I have tested it before post it

Comment: you don't need setX with this solution. Read about RelativeLayout

Comment: I've left out an important piece of information in the question. The number `EditText` and percent sign `TextView` need to be centered in their parent at all times, unless the number is empty, then the right margin to the percent sign must apply. Which means `setX()` must be called because it's the only way to override the default centering of `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: What I want to do is restore the default centering behavior when it goes from empty to unempty, but that behavior won't return if I've called `setX()`.

Comment: I need to use `setX()`, it's part of the requirement, part of the UX, the percent sign must be repositioned when the number is empty.

Comment: And now I'm finding that in a `RelativeLayout` when gravity is set to centered, `setX()` doesn't even work on `percentSignTextView`.

Comment: setX() can't be a requirement. centered percentage sign can be a requirement. how can you achieve that? I mean: if you have perc centered it result in a 0 width EditText. And with a 0 width EditText how can user tap it to insert data?

Comment: `setX()` is not used to center the percent sign, if you'll read the question you'll see that `setX()` is used to position the percent sign at a constant distance from the right end of the parent, in fact leaving even more room for the `EditText` to be interacted with when it's empty. But that's not the purpose of it, it's a UX requirement, simple as that.

Comment: I can't understand what you need, sorry

Comment: if you can post a screenshot

Comment: Yes, remove the setX from that solution, and voila :)))